# No Available Proxy For Country - 80203 error from Twilio

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I am using the node twilio module to use the twilio proxy service. I created the service and bought a US number from the console. In my code, I create a session and whenever I try to add a participant with a non-US phone number to the session, I get the **80203** error: **This Service has no available Proxy numbers for country code** . I am using my trial account and I registered the participant's number as a verified caller id in the console.

The documentation says that twilio will first try to assign the participant one of your purchased proxy numbers from the same country, and if you haven't purchased a proxy phone number from the same country, you can still use a number from a different country to reach you and your customers.

My question is, why do I keep getting this error when assigning numbers from a different country as proxy when the documentation says that is allowed?

Answer (score 0):

I had your same problem. Then I solved passing the proxyIdentifier's optional property when creating the participant.
See https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/80203

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though the link might answer the question, It is better to add the consolidated details out here so that the answer stands out even if the link is broken in future.

Comment: Yes you're right, but even if the link is broken in future, the answer is just this phrase "you need to pass the proxyIdentifier's optional property when creating the participant". No need to say anything else in order to solve this problem.